# Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema whent running a React demo project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to run a react project using nodejs.

According to the tutorial it is using web pack server. But when I am starting the project it is giving the below error

```
Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema
```

I have installed the web server package project inside the same directory where I have created the node project and inside package.json I have server configuration like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
```

Comment: have you installed webpack-dev-server globally?

Comment: can you share your webpack version in package.json?

Comment: Could you share your webpack configuration please?

Comment: I have installed it using c drive also

Comment: This is the version    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"

Comment: try to remove ^ from 2.4.5 and then check

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps

```
npm uninstall webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev
```